# How to provide values from a class which is not an entity to a repository in spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have a doubt about Spring Data and Spring Repositories.
I need to provide some values to a CrudRepository from another class which is not an Entity. For example:
I Have a class

```
@Entity
class Profile {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private long birthDate;
   private String aboutMe;
   ...
}
```

and

```
class MyProfile {
   private String profileId;
   private String accountId;
   private String name;
   private String aboutMe;
}
```

and a Repository

```
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, String>{

    @Transactional
    Profile findByAccountId(String id);

    void updateMyProfile(MyProfile myProfile);
}
```

and I would like to update only some fields from Profile using data provided in MyProfile. There is a way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the update query manually:

```
@Query("UPDATE Profile p" +
        " SET " +
        " p.name = ?#{#myprofile.name}, " +
        " p.aboutMe = ?#{#myprofile.aboutMe}" +
        " p.account.id = ?#{#myprofile.accountId}" + // I assume that account is another entity
        " WHERE p.id = ?#{#myprofile.profileId}")
@Transactional
@Modifying
void updateMyProfile(@Param("myprofile") MyProfile myprofile);
```